# How to get rid of prompt notification when "automatically" turning on Wi-Fi?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9

On my Galaxy s9, I have the setting "turn on Wi-Fi automatically" enabled. When I enter a known network, I get a notification where I am prompted if I want to connect to that network or not.

How is that automatic? Can I instead silently connect/disconnect to known Wi-Fi:s?

Comment: Are the Wifis that you get an the prompt for encrypted or unencrypted?

Comment: Encrypted. WPA2 PSK is what I read in the information of the last encountered access point.

Comment: I'd understand that for "unknown networks" (which my now deleted answer was targeting), but agree for *known* networks it should *connect* automatically. But no idea what Samsung is doing there.